# How to configure vscode with torch7 on Ubuntu?

Tags: lua, torch, visual-studio-code

I download Lua and Ravi 5.3 Debugger plug-in and change lanuch.json. I just add all the paths in torch-activate into it.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Ravi Debugger",
        "type": "lua",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.lua",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "LUA_PATH": "$/home/yan/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/yan/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/home/yan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/yan/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;./?.lua;/home/yan/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua",
        "LUA_CPATH": "/home/yan/torch/install/lib/?.so;/home/yan/.luarocks/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/home/yan/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;./?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so"
    }
]
}
```

Then the error happens with message:

```
Debugger initialized
Program terminated with error: error loading module 'libpaths' from file '/home/yan/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so':
/home/yan/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/libpaths.so: undefined symbol: lua_replace
```

I haven't google the correct solution to it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using lua 5.1. If you check the description of Lua ann Ravi 5.3 Debugger you can find this comment:

> You may not be able to debug Lua 5.0, 5.1 or 5.2 scripts - only 5.3 is tested and officially supported

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16809070)

Comment: @user1438038 I think the answer user8357547 is giving is that OP's version of lua (5.1) is the cause of the problem. Presumably the solution would be to upgrade to version 5.3?